# Joining queries in informix

Tags: sql, database, join, informix

I currently have 2 queries (which I have taken from various pages on the internet) which do the following:

- Retrieve all the columns for a given table
- Retrieve the PK and FK constraints on a given table

These queries respectively are

```
select 
    c.colname, 
    c.coltype, 
    c.collength
from 
    syscolumns c, 
    systables t
where 
    t.tabname = 'user' and 
    c.tabid = t.tabid
```

and

```
select 
    c.colname, 
    c.colno, 
    o.constrtype 
from 
    systables t,
    sysconstraints o,
    sysindexes i,
    syscolumns c
where 
    t.tabname = 'user' and 
    c.tabid = t.tabid and
    o.tabid = t.tabid and 
    i.tabid = t.tabid and 
    o.constrtype in ('R', 'P') and 
    o.idxname = i.idxname and 
    (   colno = part1 or 
        colno = part2 or 
        colno = part3 or 
        colno = part4 or 
        colno = part5 or 
        colno = part6 or 
        colno = part7 or 
        colno = part8 or 
        colno = part10 or 
        colno = part9 or 
        colno = part11 or 
        colno = part12 or 
        colno = part13 or 
        colno = part14 or 
        colno = part15 or 
        colno = part16 );
```

I would like to join these queries together so that the result contains something like
`colname`, `colno`, `collength`, `constrtype`. I believe a LEFT OUTER JOIN is what I need but I'm not quite sure how to form it so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not intimately familiar with Informix's metadata table structure, so I will assume that the queries you have are correct.

I think you just want to get the full set of columns.  The following query should do this:

```
select c.colname, c.colno,   o.constrtype 
from systables t left outer join
     syscolumns c
     on c.tabid = t.tabid left outer join
     sysconstraints o
     on o.tabid = t.tabid left outer join
     sysindexes i
     on i.tabid = t.tabid and
        o.idxname = i.idxname
where t.tabname = 'user' and 
      o.constrtype in ('R', 'P') and 
      colno in (part1, part2, part3, part4, part5, part6, part7, part8, part9, part10,
                part11, part12, part13, part14, part15, part16
               )
```

I changed the query to use modern join syntax.  You should not use commas in the `from` clause.  Instead, you should use explicit join syntax.  In addition, I changed the sequence of comparisons to part to an `in` statement.  Finally, I start with the tables and make all the joins `left outer join`s.